# Getting data from matplotlib axes object

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to determine what the data points are on a matplotlib [axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib-axes).  Is there an attribute I'm missing on the [Axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib-axes) object to get the x/y data values?

For example, say my code is passed a line plot, and I want to print out the x/y values that are plotted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `plot` call will give you a `lines.Line2D`, which has the `get_xdata(orig=True)` and the `get_ydata(orig=True)` methods.

You can check `axes.get_children()` for `Line2D` instances.

Note that what you're doing sounds horrible from a software design point of view. You should rather implement something like a wrapper for `plot` that prints your raw data.

@JRichardSnape adds that iff your plot is only lines, you can use `get_lines()` rather than filtering the output of `get_children()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I disagree with your comment about being 'horrible from a software design point of view'.  I'm trying to work with a third-party library that returns plots.  I'm not creating the plots myself.  So, I have to ask the plot what its' data is.

Comment: @durden2.0: I didn't say *your* design choices were horrible :)

Comment: @durden2.0 furthermore, maybe you could just rename the axes.plot function to something like axes.oldplot in your matplotlib installation, and write that minimal wrapper. Or the hell, just modify the source code of the software you're using, if you can get it. For anything that plots data, I'd urge the author twice to give you the source code -- don't trust any graphical representation that you haven't faked yourself!

Comment: That's a good point. I could just change the source code in matplotlib or the other library.  However, then I have to remember that change when I upgrade either library.  I'm trying to avoid modifying other packages if possible to avoid breaking anything in those libraries and maintaining my own forks for such a small change.

Comment: well, giving the user the ability to access the data that the user *should* get definitively is a big step in the right direction -- you say fork, so I presume this is FOSS? then, for the sake of good software, contribute back, so that others might benefit, too!

Comment: A little sub-note - I was going to write an answer, but it appears this has resolved it.  If (and only if, I think) the data on your plots are lines (rather than collections generated by `plt.scatter()` for instance) you can use `get_lines()` rather than `get_children()` and then you get only `Line2D` objects, not all artists that you then have to filter.