# Matplotlib Axes Object, Get Data for Colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a function that does some plotting and returns an axes object:

```
def custom_plot(x, y, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    ax.scatter(x, y)

    return ax

ax = custom_plot(range(10), range(10))

colorbar(ax)
```

The last line will throw an error (as it should).  `ax.get_children()` returns  list of the line objects, so not suitable to pass to the colorbar.  Is it possible to access the scatter object via the axes or is it necessary to also return the scatter, e.g. `s = plot.scatter(x,y,);return ax, scatter`.

Similar, but not an answer:

- [Getting data from matplotlib axes object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161960/getting-data-from-matplotlib-axes-object)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, misunderstood the question. From the source the scatter function only seems to return a path collection and not add it in any way that I noticed it to the axes class.

Depending on the conditions of your plot the easiest way to achieve that is just to replicate your plot into the colorbar instruction:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def custom_plot(x, y, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    ax.scatter(x, y, c = x) 

    return ax

x,y = range(10), range(10)
ax = custom_plot(x,y)
plt.colorbar(ax.scatter(x, y, c = x)) 
plt.show()
```

Effectively you are reproducing the plot from the axes without a shortcut variable. It's not, however, an ideal solution to your problem.

NOTE: I'll leave this post here just in case it might help you. If not tell me and I'll delete it.

**ORIGINAL POST:**

You can create a variable for the scatter plot itself and use that as argument. That being said you also should provide a map variable for the color. The following example adapted from your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def custom_plot(x, y, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    axp = ax.scatter(x, y, c = x) # You have to give a map variable for the colorbar.

    return ax,axp # also return the plot itself

ax,axp = custom_plot(range(10), range(10))

plt.colorbar(axp) # give the plot as argument to colorbar
plt.show()
```

, results in this:

[image: Creating colorbar from outside the function plot]

Comment: Thanks.  This is the solution I propose after describing the problem.  No method to access the scatter via the axes exists?

Comment: @Jzl5325 Sorry. I've edited my post but with an half solution. You do reproduce your data from the axes but only by reproducing the plot itself. It seems very inefficient. If it helps you good, if not tell me so so I can delete the post. Best of luck.

Comment: Update looks good.  Not ideal, but definitely a solution.  It looks like I could even get the data from the line objects back off of the axis and then pipe that in as the new plot. (The example is super simple, but the actual plot function does more data manipulation.)